# JMSComponent>transacted=true and transacted() in camel builder

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

How transacted() in camel DSL is related to transacted="true" of JMSComponent.
Will that make any sense, if transacted property of JMSComponent is set to "true" along with transacted() in camel DSL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transacted="true"` in JMS component configuration makes your JMS consumer transacted. So this is required if you want to make sure you don't lose messages.

However, you have multiple options to enable transactions (see the [Camel docs for details](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jms/src/main/docs/jms-component.adoc#enabling-transacted-consumption)).

1. Use local JMS transactions
2. Use your own Spring transaction manager

The Camel DSL `transacted()` is only necessary if you go with the second option, it [references a `SpringTransactionPolicy`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/transactional-client.adoc#transaction-policies) (for example `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`). If it is present in your route, Camel is looking for a Spring transaction manager to use.

If you use option 1 (what is simpler in configuration and perfectly suitable if you only talk to a single JMS broker), you don't need the Camel DSL `transacted()` and your JMS consumer routes are nevertheless transactional.

**Addition due to comments**

To use option 1, you only have to set `transacted="true"` and `lazyCreateTransactionManager="false"` on your Camel `ActiveMQComponent`. You must not configure a Spring transaction manager (if you do, you end up with two tx managers!)

If you want to be transactional between multiple JMS brokers or a broker and a Database, you would either need [XA transactions](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA) or you have to implement compensation logic to handle the edge cases when using simple transactions with each system involved.

Comment: So, for point 2, it seems that we don't require transacted="true" in JMSComponent ? is this what your are mentioning. ?

Comment: No, transacted="true" in JMS component configuration is always required. I just edited my answer to make this point more clear.

Comment: I am familiar with Springs Platform Transaction Manager, but not sure about local JMS transactions. Could you please explain in detail. Also, could you please explain transaction management when multiple resources (like db and jms ) are involved

Comment: There are no big details. I added how to configure it and it simply works. Give it a try. However XA transactions is a huge and complex subject. I try to avoid it whenever possible :-)